# HTTPBuilder and formUrlEncoded

Tags: groovy

First, sorry i am a newbie in groovy

I'm trying to make a request to google with HTTPBuilder (https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder)

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#obtainingacode

Here is my code

```
def code = new HTTPBuilder(oauthUrl).request(POST, URLENC) { req ->
    body = [client_id: clientId, scope: 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']

    headers.'Accept' = 'application/json'
    headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        println resp.statusLine
        println reader
        println reader.text
    }
    response.failure = { resp, reader ->
        println resp.statusLine
        println reader.text
    }
}
```

When i run this code, i get an output for `println reader` moreover `resp.statusLine` show me 200 Ok, but I get a `null` for `println reader.text`

I don't understand why this happen ...

The same request with curl send me the right response

```
{
  "device_code" : "XXXXX",
  "user_code" : "XXXX",
  "verification_url" : "https://www.google.com/device",
  "expires_in" : 1800,
  "interval" : 5
}
```

## Edit

Here is the ouput

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- [{ "device_code" : "XXXk", "user_code" : "XXX", "verification_url" : "https://www.google.com/device", "expires_in" : 1800, "interval" : 5 }:null]
- null

## Edit 2

I can access to the response with the following code (I'm not sure it is a clean code)

```
response.success = { resp, reader ->
    def stream
    reader.each { key, value ->
        stream = key
    }
    stream
}
```

Comment: I assume `println reader` prints out a map of that response?

Comment: I have added an edit to show output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `reader` is an already parsed `Map` - you don't get an instance of stream, but the already parsed response. Since there's no `text` key you get null. Try:

```
println reader.device_code
```

it should work well.

You can also check what is `reader` with:

```
println reader.getClass()
```

Comment: `println reader.device_code` prints `null` and `println reader.getClass()` prints `java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: Ok, so this is as I said: `reader` is `Map`, and it has no `text` and `device_code` keys. You can just `reader` as a plain groovy `Map`.